# create column flag containing word from list

Tags: python, string, pandas

I want to add a flag to my python pandas dataframe, if an entry in the column contains the word from a list

for any separete row we can use

```
any(word in train['a'][0] for word in words)
```

I tried to make a pattern

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
words=['photos','pictures', ' pics ', 'pix', 'image']
pattern = '|'.join(words)

train=pd.DataFrame()
train['a']=words
```

I've tried with contains but it didn't get the pattern

```
def emb_col_1(tr, te, col, pat, suf):
    tr["0_"+col+suf]=0
    tr.loc[tr[col].str.contains(pat), "0_"+col+suf] =1
    #tr.loc[tr[col].str.count(pat)>0, "0_"+col+suf] =1
    #tr.loc[(word in tr[col].str for word in pat), "0_"+col+suf] =1
    #tr["0_"+col+suf] = np.where(tr[col].str.contains(pat, case=False, na=False), 1, 0)
    #tr["0_"+col+suf] = np.where(any(word in train[col] for word in pat), 1, 0)


emb_col_1(train, test, 'a', words, '_p')
emb_col_1(train, test, 'a', pattern, '_p')
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you use `return tr` in the end of function?

Comment: thanks, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
words=['photos','pictures', ' pics ', 'pix', 'image']
#remeove trailining whitespaces by strip
pattern = '|'.join([x.strip() for x in words])

train=pd.DataFrame()
#added more values for test
train['a']=words + ['a','pics sss']
print (train)

#remove unused te
def emb_col_1(tr, col, pat, suf):
    #convert True and Falses to 1 and 0 by astype(int)
    tr["0_"+col+suf] = tr[col].str.contains(pat, case=False, na=False).astype(int)
    #return DataFrame
    return tr


df1 = emb_col_1(train, 'a', pattern, '_p')
print (df1)
          a  0_a_p
0    photos      1
1  pictures      1
2     pics       1
3       pix      1
4     image      1
5         a      0
6  pics sss      1
```

EDIT:

```
words=['photos',' pics ', 'pix', 'image']
#remeove trailining whitespaces by strip
pattern = '|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(x.strip()) for x in words])

train=pd.DataFrame()
#added more values for test
train['a']=words + ['a','pics sss', 'pictures']
print (train)
          a
0    photos
1     pics 
2       pix
3     image
4         a
5  pics sss
6  pictures

#remove unused te
def emb_col_1(tr, col, pat, suf):
    #convert True and Falses to 1 and 0 by astype(int)
    tr["0_"+col+suf] = tr[col].str.contains(pat, case=False, na=False).astype(int)
    #return DataFrame
    return tr


df1 = emb_col_1(train, 'a', pattern, '_p')
print (df1)
          a  0_a_p
0    photos      1
1     pics       1
2       pix      1
3     image      1
4         a      0
5  pics sss      1
6  pictures      0
```

Comment: One comment - pattern will be applied even if the word in [words] is a part of the word in string (not a separate word) Like pattern 'picture' will count also 'pictures'

Comment: I think it should working nice, there is some problem?

Comment: Yes, then need word boundary I think you need change `pattern = '|'.join([x.strip() for x in words])` to `pattern = '|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(x) for x in words])`.Can you check it?

Comment: it can be misleading in some cases. For example pattern 'pic' will be counted in 'picture', 'picnik' etc.

Comment: I edit answer with my comment, added was strip. also data in `words` was changed and also `train['a']=words + ['a','pics sss', 'pictures']`. Now last `pictures` is not matched.

Comment: probably combination of two works better `pattern = '|'.join([r'\b{}\b'.format(x.strip()) for x in words])`

Comment: Yes, I think so ;)

Comment: Thank you once again for your help!